# Was the release of "Barbie" intentionally coordinated to be on the same day as "Oppenheimer"?

Tags: oppenheimer, barbie

Both "Barbie" and "Oppenheimer" were release on July 21st, 2023. Was this a pure coincidence or was this intentional for marketing purposes?

Comment: Why would competing companies coordinate release dates?

Comment: Companies often coordinate when it's mutually beneficial to, and it certainly seems that the "barbieheimer" buzz has benefited both box offices,  so it's not unbelievable.

Comment: @JonathanReez seems it has happened at least 16 times: https://www.insider.com/big-movies-released-same-day-2023-7

Answer (score 45):

Press reports have cited a single apparently well known reason as to why Oppenheimer was released when it was, and not moved or otherwise delayed with regards to WB's Barbie release.

Barmar in comments does allude to a reason why WB felt they did not have to move their date either - their product in terms of name, brand, director and cast, were strong enough to stand on their own against any competitor.

> So why hasn’t either Universal or Warner Bros blinked? Why have they both resolutely held the line, and not shuffled a week or two either way to give each other space.
>
> Well, half of that is easy to answer: **Universal can’t**.
>
> The backdrop to why goes back to when Christopher Nolan opted to end his two decade working relationship with Warner Bros at the end of 2020. The metaphorical straw that broke the relationship was Warner Bros deciding to put its entire slate of 2021 releases simultaneously on its HBO Max streaming service as they went into cinemas. Nolan was not shy about relaying his views to The Hollywood Reporter, in an infamous statement that read “some of our industry’s biggest filmmakers and most important movie stars went to bed the night before thinking they were working for the greatest movie studio and woke up to find out they were working for the worst streaming service”.
>
> What this meant was pretty much every other studio in town bidding for Nolan’s services, with the exception of Disney. And why wouldn’t they? Nolan’s track record of regularly delivering individual films that succeed commercially is surely now unparalleled in modern cinema. Who wouldn’t want to be in the Christopher Nolan business? Well, apart from Disney.
>
> But **Nolan had conditions**. A $100m production budget for his new movie, and guaranteed levels of marketing support. **A summer release date, and reportedly, a commitment from Universal that it wouldn’t release any other film three weeks either side of Oppenheimer.**
>
> This bit’s important: Universal is by distance the most prolific of the major traditional Hollywood studios, and the only one regularly releasing into cinemas more than ten films a year. Nolan asked for a concentration of studio efforts on his next movie, and Universal happily agreed. As such, **after Wes Anderson’s Asteroid City** releases towards the end of June, it has **no further film until Speak No Evil on August 9th.**
>
> What this means is that **Universal is bound into its release date**: if it opted to move one film, it’s **got to move others.** And it’d *risk alienating a filmmaker it worked hard to woo.* .
>
> After all, if it was going to shift, surely it would have done so by now, and not two months before it was due to release – a move in itself that’d be **perceived as a panic measure**

https://filmstories.co.uk/features/barbie-vs-oppenheimer-why-has-neither-film-switched-its-release-date/

> Despite the excitement around what will likely be this year’s biggest day in film, many have questioned why Barbie and Oppenheimer have stuck to the same release date. Directors and studios are known to consider release dates with great care, dodging competitors to ensure box office success. Picking a suitable release date can make or break a film.
>
> look at the **deal director Christopher Nolan made with Universal** when he agreed to partner with them on the film. Leaving his 19-year relationship with Warner Bros behind, Nolan signed a deal with Universal in 2021. The deal stipulated a number of terms, including a summer release date for Oppenheimer. It also **required a three week exclusivity period meaning, to secure the film, Universal had to ensure that no other films would be scheduled for three weeks either side of Friday, July 21st.**
>
> The conditions of the deal mean that in order to move the release of Oppenheimer, **Universal would have had to reschedule a number of other films, such as Wes Anderson’s Asteroid City**. Unlike Nolan, Gerwig’s **Barbie faces no logistical limitations.** Their commitment to the release date seems to come from **sheer confidence in the film’s box office appeal**, underpinned by a relentless marketing campaign, taking a much louder approach than Nolan.
>
> It’s unlikely that the two films would have received so much external hype without this competitive element. Though the deal between Nolan and Universal limited their control over the clash, it might actually bolster the film’s success.

https://faroutmagazine.co.uk/why-did-barbie-and-oppenheimer-choose-the-same-release-date/

Other notes from press:

> Cinephiles haven't seen a divide like Barbie vs Oppenheimer since July 2008 when The Dark Knight and Mamma Mia! went head-to-head at the Box Office.

I did have a bunch of articles to go through but lost them when I didnt think i had enough for an answer and just wrote a comment earlier instead.

Comment: Also... How many people want to go see both Openheimer and Barbie... I'd imagine the intersection of that Venn Diagram is tiny

Comment: @ScottishTapWater according to https://www.cnbc.com/2023/07/10/amc-has-sold-20000-barbie-and-oppenheimer-double-feature-tickets.html AMC sold 20k double feature tickets

Comment: This says why Openheimer didn't move but doesn't say why Barbie didn't move. This doesn't answer OP's question of coincidence vs intentional. It's still good info though.

Answer (score 23):

The decision to release both Barbie and Oppenheimer on the same date, July 21, 2023, was not a coincidence. It was a calculated move by Warner Bros., the studio behind Barbie, to take revenge on Christopher Nolan, the director of Oppenheimer. Nolan had enjoyed a long and fruitful relationship with Warner Bros., but in 2020, [the two sides had a falling out and parted ways on bad terms](https://badgerherald.com/artsetc/2021/09/20/after-almost-20-years-christopher-nolan-warner-bros-have-called-it-quits/). By releasing Barbie on the same date as Oppenheimer, Warner Bros. [may have been hoping to](https://www.koimoi.com/hollywood-news/oppenheimer-vs-barbie-box-office-clash-is-a-warner-bros-manufactured-battle-to-take-revenge-on-christopher-nolan-universal/) hurt Nolan’s box office success.

Comment: It's a plausible theory, and you've got motive and opportunity accounted for there; but do you have any evidence it was indeed deliberate by a Warner Bros exec for this reason?

Comment: This is the accepted reason but its extremely unlikely any evidence can be found for it as its almost certainly actionable.

Comment: @Paulie_D - The idea that a studio would intentionally act to spite a director is a pretty big claim to make with no backup

Comment: I think you underestimate the pettiness of studio executives. Nevertheless, my reading etc. is that this is what happened. It's just generally "know", I don't know anything about it's veracity.

Comment: Kind of a dubious plan though, as they're not exactly similar types of movies. If they really wanted to cause harm, WB had other films that are at least marginally closer to  Oppenheimer in tone and genre. Why not play this game with one of those?

Comment: Isn't this cutting off your nose to spite your face? It would seem to me that *both* movies would make less than they would have without another big film releasing the same day. Would WB really try to hurt Nolan's box office success at the cost of their own? Although, I suppose you might have more of the Oppenheimer audience seeing Barbie instead rather than the reverse.

Comment: As near as I can tell, this claim is sourced from a Puck report. Unfortunately, Puck has a paywall so I can't check that out myself. The link near the end of this answer goes into the claim, but is one of the worst clickbaity popup-adrific websites I've ever seen. I wouldn't advice clicking on it.

Comment: These 2 movies have different target audiences (and thus not competitors) so I wouldn't expect either to suffer any loss from being on the same date. There are certainly people who want to see both movies but I would imagine most of them would see both movies instead of picking their favorite. And if there's no downside then there's no reason not to have them air on the same date (and thus "coincidence"). Which is to say that this "revenge" theory doesn't make sense.